# Why Nav Controller can't be declared as class variable?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to android and working through some tutorials. Currently working on implementing the Navigation controller and overriding the up button functionality. Part of doing this is to link the action bar with the Nav controller and overriding onSupportNavigateUp(). In doing this I noticed that we have to fetch the Nav Controller by id twice so I decided to create a class variable that does this and re-use the variable. The problem is the App crashes on startup when I do this. My guess is this is because I'm trying to get the Nav Controller before inflating the views?

So my question is why does this work:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you are assigning the `navController` before the view is inflated and passed the null to `setupActionBarWithNavController`
You can do it like this,

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that works! I should add that in order for this to work you need to declare the val as `private lateinit var navController: NavController`